# How does PipedInputStream read from an OutputStream?

Tags: java, java-io

How does a `PipedInputStream` read from a `PipedOutputStream`? Is it using `toString()` or is there some hidden magic to access a `private` member variable?

Comment: What makes you think that it reads from an output stream? Please clarify your question.

Comment: `protected` and default access ("package-private") variables can be accessed within the same package, which is what is happening between `PipedInputStream` and `**Piped**OutputStream`.

Comment: It doesn't. It reads from a `PipedOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PipedOutputStream.write(int byte)` will simply call the `protected` method `PipedInputStream.receive(int byte)` which in turn will simply fill its own buffer. Same thing for the bulk read/write methods.

Please note that the internal buffer in `PipedInputStream` is not `private` but `protected` and therefore accessible in the same way as the `protected` `receive()` methods. But `PipedOutputStream` plays fair and does not access it directly.

This works of course, because `protected` methods and fields are accessible not only by deriving classes but by the complete package as shown in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Access_modifiers).

No need for "magic" like "toString".

Comment: Didn't realize that was the case. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have a background thread which reads from the OutputStream and writes what it read to the PipedInputStream until it is finished.